# wpf c# check exist object in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi every one
i have a question

if there is a grid built by xaml, and in that grid there are many object created prgrammically by c#.

how to accsess that objects or know there are objects in that grid.

for example. in my grid first is empty, but after i click the button out site of the grid, that create some object like textblock and listbox. nah I have one other button to check and listing what object in that grid. this the xaml code :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TabControl Margin="0,0,0,141">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Button Content="Create Object" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,0,0,54.04" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="105"/>
        <Button Content="check object" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,237,54.04" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="82" Margin="0,0,100,21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="101"/>
    </Grid>
```

please help me

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand the problem completely. But one thing I noticed: The way the grid is currently setup, your newly added items will be overlapping one another since they're all being placed in row 0, col 0 (No row or column definitions set). Second, it may first help to set the Grid's Name property. At least this way you can access it in the code behind.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the easiest thing to do, but it's been written already so it's up to you to understand how it works and use it: Linq to Visual Tree 
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/ 
It helped me in a project I was working on.

Comment: It may not be the performance beast but it sure does return all objects with a familiar query interface given by Linq which I thought was really cool when I first saw it, and it is! :)